# Will the focus confirmation dot still operate with non CPU lenses on a D3200?

Tags: nikon, manual-focus

I've seen some lenses that have an AE chip already in them (ex. the Rokinon 35mm f/1.4), but is it necessary to have a fully manual lens chipped in order for the focus confirmation dot to work? ( and I'm not talking about the rangefinder, I already know it doesn't operate in M mode )

Answer (score 1):

The green dot should work, it is a function of the phase shift viewfinder. It's about the view seen, not about the lens communication.